# Permanently install PCL font to printer

Tags: fonts, printer, pcl

After loading a software font (`.SFP`) into an HP M506 printer (e.g. E13B for printing checks), it appears in the "HP PCL5e Permanent Soft Fonts" list and is available for use. However, after the printer loses power, the so-called "permanent" font is lost.

How can the font be made available to the printer at startup? Several vendors sell USB drives with fonts that can be installed, but I have been unable to find documentation regarding creating such a drive with an already-licensed font file.

I've attempted the obvious step of simply placing the font file on an unused USB drive and starting the printer with it plugged in to the rear port, but the font was not loaded. This model printer also has available an extra USB module to allow such a drive to be mounted internally, but I have been similarly unable to find any documentation to explain if that USB port functions differently from the rear USB port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all administrative actions for HP devices are done through HP web [jetadmin](https://www8.hp.com/us/en/solutions/business-solutions/printingsolutions/wja.html) from hp.

The font is uploaded into Web Jetadmin, then it can connect to the printer's available storage devices (including the USB) and download the font to it.

It creates a folder structure on the USB, along with a few configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

When you download fonts to a printer they are stored in RAM. Hence, they will be lost when the printer is reset. To store the fonts permanently, the printer needs to have a hard disk installed. Once that is installed, the fonts can be loaded onto it, either via a supplied utility, or via the printer's web interface.

A 500GB drive is available for your printer, part number [5851-6417](https://www.iteminconline.com/5851-6417_5851-6417-hp-m527-hard-drive.htm) (also a secure hard disk B5L29-67903). Note that standard hard drives are very unlikely to work with the printer. I found the [Installation Guide](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/guid-73380e56-ae85-42ee-889a-8ea7772bf62d_en_us_guid-dc5e7c0d-728d-4490-bc68-7c19c3225775), but so far no instruction manual.

Comment: I used a standard 2.5" ssd in M712 that had a failed hard drive.  I had to use the built-in admin menu to format it properly.  However, after a bit of poking around I got it to work just fine.  Can't guarentee that for your model, but I unplug the main circuit board where the network card, and there was a spot for a 2.5" laptop hdd.

Comment: Can't say for certain on the drive itself, but your link illustrates that there is a bracket and adapter card that is required (and probably only available with the drive). Thanks for the info--I'm still hoping to find some details on loading it via USB.

Comment: As far as I know, printers cannot use fonts from a USB drive.

Comment: On the M712 all the mounting infrastructure is part of the PCB, and it takes any 2.5" hard drive.  Just take the screws out, and put them back in the new drive.